# How to implement Django social login using google for different type of users(eg: candidate ,employer, customer)

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-social-auth

I want to implement Social login in my Django project. When I searched about it, I found social login for only one user. But I want to implement it for different type of users as I mentioned in the title. Can anyone suggest a solution to implement this in my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can allow auto-registration to everybody. But, to be registered on your app doesn't mean user can do anything in app. Only users on group `candidate` , `employer` or `customer` are allowed to see data or perform operations in app.

Then, you can create views on your app to put users on group. For example, a user of the grup `employer` can assign users to group `customer`.

Comment: What I have planned is that , During the time of registration type of the user is also added to the database(using Django User model).During the time of login, according to the type of user ,user will redirect to the corresponding user home page. For example, if a user registered as an 'employer' when he or she login with his login credentials he or she redirected to employer home page. Similarly for other type of users.@dani herrera

Comment: On registration time, how to check that the user is what he says he is? Any user can self-registrated as `employer`?

Comment: In this case, I have used three registration forms for each type of users. Here I have implemented three radio buttons(for customer, candidate and employer). For example, If a user wants to register as a candidate, he or she can click on the candidate radio button. At that time candidate registration form will display. And he can enter his or her details and register with the web app. Similarly in the case of other type of users. And it is implemented by javascript. In each form social login authentication has to be implemented.@dani herrera